# Issue with "npm install"

Tags: node.js

When I try to do "npm install" on my mac, I get this particular error
"npm WARN deprecated point-geometry@0.0.0: This module has moved: please install @mapbox/point-geometry instead"

I have tried doing "npm install mapbox/point-geometry". And then again ran the command - "npm install". I still get the same warning. I have updated my packages to latest versions but that did not help either.
Please help me on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions seeking for help solving a specific problem should be accompanied with a [MCVE]. This question could use a lot more information before we can understand what's going on. In particular, what project are you attempting to `npm install` on? Can you show the respective package.json? What versions of npm and Node.js are you using? Also note that that message is only a warning, not an error. Have you stumbled upon other issues that makes you think the warning is important?

Comment: @E_net4: I understand his concerns, as depreciated warnings can potentially make it break in the future. I also get this warning. The package I suspect is loaded because of a dependency to this from openlayers in my case.

Comment: @awe I did not discard the possibility of the warning becoming a problem, but there doesn't seem to be enough information in this question to unequivocally address the matter. The OP hasn't even replied or updated the question since it was asked, which was almost 3 months ago.